# calling sigprocmask from bash

Tags: bash, signals

I have a process that spawn a bash command with `system()` while the signal mask has all the signals blocked. This cannot be fixed easily.

The bash command eventually `exec`s into a process. The all blocked signal mask is inherited from the original process through bash to the final process, so in the end I get a process that is "immune" to all the signals (except of course `SIGKILL`, `SIGSTOP`, etc).

The workaround would be resetting `sigprocmask` from bash, but I cannot find any related command. Is it possible to do?

Comment: Is there a `bash` script that you can modify? What is the exact call to `system` involved?

Comment: It seems to me that this is not possible (whyever): "Non-builtin  commands  run  by bash have signal handlers set to the values inherited by the shell from its parent."

Comment: @chepner I can modify the bash command that is invoked, but not the fact that when it's invoked the process has an all blocked signals set.

Comment: I don't think this is possible with bash. Can you use ksh93 or mksh instead? Or call the final process via yet another process (ksh, perl, python, …)?

Comment: @Gilles python and perl are possible

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a pure bash solution.

Ksh (both ksh93 and mksh) unblock all signals (tested on Debian wheezy), so if you can use ksh instead of bash, it will solve your problem.

If you can't change the fact that bash is invoked, you might be able to make bash execute ksh and make ksh execute the child process: replace

```
bash -c '…; exec child_process'
```

by

```
bash -c '…; exec ksh -c "exec child_process"'
```

Beware of quoting issues!

Ksh is fast and easy to use, but often not part of the default installation. If that is an issue, you can use Perl instead, which is part of the default installation in most non-embedded Linux systems.

```
perl -e '
    use POSIX;
    $s = POSIX::SigSet->new(); $s->fillset();
    sigprocmask(1, $s, $s) or die $!;    # 1 = SIG_UNBLOCK
    exec "child_process"'
```

Answer (score 4):

env in coreutils >= v8.31 will have this functionality

```
env --default-signal your_prog
```